# Scrollable panel and MenuBar in Vaadin?

Tags: view, vaadin, panel, vaadin7

I'm trying to make a view consisting of a scrollable VerticalLayout and a MenuBar at the bottom. The height of the whole view would take up only the screen. It seems that wrapping the layout in a panel is the only way to make it scrollable. I followed the example in Vaadin's documentation and wrote the following:

```
VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
layout.setMargin(true);
layout.setSpacing(true);
layout.setSizeUndefined();

Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.setContent(lLayout);
panel.setSizeFull();
panel.getContent().setSizeUndefined();

MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();

addComponent(panel);
addComponent(menu);

// minimizes the menu bar and maximizes panel in layout
setExpandRatio(panel, 1);
setExpandRatio(menu, 0);
```

When I run the app, however, the whole view becomes scrollable (meaning I had to scroll down to get to the menu bar).

Comment: What is the outer layout you put the panel and menu into?

Comment: It's a view extending a VerticalLayout.

Comment: Have you set this VL to fullsize (or at least full height)?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit too less information to solve your problem definetly.

But for now and for the future you should open your application in browser with parameter ?debug (https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-debug.html)

So you can break down your Views and check which parent view has the wrong parameters. Next step you can look what you should change by using firebug or chrome's inspection tool. When you have found your mistake, you write your correct code. Happy coding :-)